# Android Studio API Library Project Missing Package-Aware-r.txt File

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

This is my first post and something I've been struggling with a number of days now. I'm creating a project using Spoonacular API for my senior final project. I managed to fix a number of errors before, and it built in the terminal for a moment before suddenly getting these errors:

" * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':generateReleaseRFile'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.GenerateLibraryRFileTask$GenerateLibRFileRunnable
> C:\Users\Kerrigan\Desktop\Spoonacular\android-client\build\intermediates\symbol_list_with_package_name\release\package-aware-r.txt "

and

" * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':verifyReleaseResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
> Path 'C:\Users\Kerrigan\Desktop\Spoonacular\android-client\build\intermediates\compiled_local_resources\release\out' is not a readable directory."

Here's my gradle.build file:

```
group = 'com.spoonacular'
project.version = '1.1'

 // ** https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2

buildscript {
    ext {
        agp_version = '7.3.0'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$agp_version"
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 33
    }
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst "META-INF/DEPENDENCIES"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    // Rename the aar correctly
    libraryVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            if (outputFile != null && outputFileName.endsWith('.aar')) {
                outputFileName = "${archivesBaseName}-${version}.aar"
            }
        }
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
}

ext {
    swagger_annotations_version = "1.6.6"
    gson_version = "2.8.9"
    okhttp = "4.5.13"
    volley_version = "1.2.1"
    junit_version = "4.13.2"
    robolectric_version = "4.5.1"
    concurrent_unit_version = "0.4.6"
}

dependencies {
    implementation "io.swagger:swagger-annotations:$swagger_annotations_version"
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:$gson_version"
    implementation "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:$okhttp"
    implementation "com.android.volley:volley:${volley_version}"
    implementation "com.spoonacular:android-client:1.1"
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$junit_version"
    testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:${robolectric_version}"
    testImplementation "net.jodah:concurrentunit:${concurrent_unit_version}"
}

afterEvaluate {
    android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
        def task = project.tasks.create "jar${variant.name.capitalize()}", Jar
        task.description = "Create jar artifact for ${variant.name}"
        task.dependsOn variant.javaCompile
        task.from variant.javaCompile.destinationDir
        task.destinationDir = project.file("${project.buildDir}/outputs/jar")
        task.archiveName = "${project.name}-${variant.baseName}-${version}.jar"
        artifacts.add('archives', task);
    }
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
}
```

And my gradle.properties

```
#Wed Mar 06 14:45:03 CST 2024
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

And my Manifest.XML:

```
<manifest  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.spoonacular.client">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application />
</manifest>
```

I've updated my JDK files, my gradle, and following a number of guides to try and resolve the issue. I checked my local files but the aware-r.txt file just... isn't there. When I put one in to see if it had any reaction, after trying to build the project the file disappeared. It was like the project was deleting the files every time I tried to run it. This also happened in the release/out directory.

I am at a complete loss and no one seems to have any answers I haven't already tried. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

by opening file view in explorer you will get .gradle delete it and rebuilding the project will may helps.